# How to fix .gif with corrupted alpha channel (stuck pixels) collected with Graphicsmagick?

Tags: graphics, ffmpeg, gif, encode, graphicsmagick

I want to convert an .avi with alpha channel into a .gif.
Firstly, I use

```
ffmpeg -i source.avi -vf scale=720:-1:flags=lanczos,fps=10 frames/ffout%03d.png
```

to convert .avi to sequence of .png's with aplha channel.
Then, I use

```
gm convert -loop 0 frames/ffout*.png output.gif
```

to collect a .gif.
But it seems that pixels of the output.gif just get stuck when something opaque is rendered on top of the transparent areas.

**Here's an example:**

[image: img]

As you can see the hearts and explosions do not get derendered.

P.S.
FFMPEG output (collection on .png's) is fine.

Comment: How about sharing the AVI file?

Comment: @MarkSetchell [Here you are.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wmvno7jaw8uijar/vid.avi?dl=0)

Comment: I added my solution as an answer. Btw hope you know **GIF** does not have an alpha channel just single transparent color but that is unrelated to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not use Graphicsmagick but your **GIF** has image **disposal mode** `0` (no animation). You should use **disposal mode** `2` (clear with background) or `3` (restore previous image) both works for your **GIF**. The disposal is present in gfx extension of each frame in the `Packed` value.

So if you can try to configure encoder to use `disposal = 2` or `3` or write script that direct stream copy your **GIF** and change the `Packed` value of gfx extension chunk frame by frame. Similar to this:

- [GIF Image getting distorted on interlacing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33604815/2521214)

If you need help with the script then take a look at:

- [How to find where does Image Block start in GIF images?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32369298/2521214)
- [Decode data bytes of GIF87a raster data stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29924219/2521214)

When I tried this (**C++** script) on your **GIF** using disposal `2` I got this result:

[image: disposal=2]

The disposal is changed in **C++** like this:

```cpp
struct __gfxext
    {
    BYTE Introducer;        /* Extension Introducer (always 21h) */
    BYTE Label;             /* Graphic Control Label (always F9h) */
    BYTE BlockSize;         /* Size of remaining fields (always 04h) */
    BYTE Packed;            /* Method of graphics disposal to use */
    WORD DelayTime;         /* Hundredths of seconds to wait    */
    BYTE ColorIndex;        /* Transparent Color Index */
    BYTE Terminator;        /* Block Terminator (always 0) */
    __gfxext(){}; __gfxext(__gfxext& a){ *this=a; }; ~__gfxext(){}; __gfxext* operator = (const __gfxext *a) { *this=*a; return this; }; /*__gfxext* operator = (const __gfxext &a) { ...copy... return this; };*/
    };

__gfxext p;
p.Packed&=255-(7<<2);   // clear old disposal and leave the rest as is
p.Packed|=     2<<2;    // set new disposal=2 (the first 2 is disposal , the <<2 just shifts it to the correct position in Packed)
```

It is a good idea to leave other bits of `Packed` as are because no one knows what could be encoded in there in time ...

Comment: Excellent sleuthing! A simple way to implement this (which I have tested and it works) with **GraphicsMagick** is to use OP's original script modified like this: `gm convert -loop 0 -dispose 2 frames/*.png output.gif`

Comment: @MarkSetchell it was easy to spot as mine own C++ encoder/decoder throws info like disposal, number of clear codes per frame and much much more for debugging purposes ... I just click on the file and see what is wrong on one look :)

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I wanted. 
I cannot thank you enough!

Comment: @IvanIvanov btw this [Animated gif only loops once in Chrome and Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38082881/2521214) might interest you too as you are constructing GIFs ...